# Firestore Rules get is always null or errors out

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

it's about isAllowedWorkDayLocationData (checks if user-document.teamId and WorkDayLocationData.teamId is the same) - the global read seems to work fine and also the users{users} seems to work.

I Try to compare the property .teamId of the accessed document and the requesters /users/-Document .teamId.

Somehow it always returns false or errors out, im not sure what of both... i checked both documents and teamId is given.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {

  
  function isAllowedWorkDayLocationData(docId, userUid) {
  return 
    get(/databases/{database}/documents/users/$(userUid)).data.teamId == 
    get(/databases/{database}/documents/workDayLocationDatas/$(docId)).data.teamId;
  }  
  
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
    }
    
    match /workDayLocationDatas/{docId} {
      allow write: if isAllowedWorkDayLocationData(docId, request.auth.uid);
    }
    match /users/{user} {
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Query from the Angular Application (this was working until i implemented the rule)

```
this.afStore.collection<WorkDayLocationData>('workDayLocationDatas', ref => ref
        .where('teamId', '==', this.teamId)
        .where('locationId', '==', this.locationId)
        .where('date', '==', this.helpers.toFireStoreDate(this.workDay.date))
        .limit(1))
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe((actions: DocumentChangeAction<WorkDayLocationData>[]) => {
          console.log("i did something");
          const data = actions[0].payload.doc.data() as WorkDayLocationData;
          const id = actions[0].payload.doc.id;
          const newPersonUids = [...data.slotsPersonUids, user.uid];
          this.afStore.collection<WorkDayLocationData>('workDayLocationDatas')
            .doc(id)
            .update({
              slotsUsed: newPersonUids.length,
              slotsPersonUids: newPersonUids
            });
        });
    });
```

WorkDayLocationData interface for Properties:

```
export interface WorkDayLocationData {
    date: string;
    locationId: string;
    locationName: string;
    teamId: string;
    slotsUsed: number;
    maxSlots: number;
    slotsPersonUids: string[];
}
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow don't share pictures of code.  Copy the code into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.  For this question you should also show the client app query that isn't working with these rules.

Comment: Oh right, will do. 1 sec

Comment: the client app query only sends the updated properties: "slotsUsed" and "slotsPersonUids". It worked before implementing the rule. It's just about the rule here.

Comment: You should show that code so we can be clear exactly what is going on.

Comment: Here you go :). Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Do you get the "I did something" log? What is the teamId? Is this equal to the authenticated user.teamId?

Comment: Yes it worked... i messed up the database-variable as shown in the answer... Lost more than an hour for this. Is there a way to see firebase-rule errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function isAllowedWorkDayLocationData(docId, userUid) {
  return 
    get(/databases/{database}/documents/users/$(userUid)).data.teamId == 
    get(/databases/{database}/documents/workDayLocationDatas/$(docId)).data.teamId;
  }
```

So it turns out {database} should be $(database) and thus the correct code for the function would look like this:

```
  function isAllowedWorkDayLocationData(docId, userUid) {
  return 
    get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userUid)).data.teamId == 
    get(/databases/$(database)/documents/workDayLocationDatas/$(docId)).data.teamId;
  }
```